# Subtract dates to get remining days

Tags: django, date, python-2.7, django-views, timedelta

Subtracting Dates and find the Balance Days and to Check whether it is greater than ZERO or NOT.

**view.py**

```
fee_start_date = form.cleaned_data['fee_start_date'] '''1994-01-01 format'''
fee_end_date = form.cleaned_data['fee_end_date'] '''1994-01-01 format'''

def date_check(start_date,end_date):
       rem = datetime.timedelta(start_date) - datetime.timedelta(end_date)
       if rem > 0:
            return False
       else:
            return True
```

Comment: I'm new to Django,So if there is any mistake in the quakity of code or the question ..Please correct it :) !

Comment: its not django related, convert strings you're getting in `fee_*_date` to datetime object and then just compare. `return fee_end_date > fee_start_date`. You don't even need to convert to datetime, just compare the strings

Comment: But,how to convert **fee_*_date** to **datetime** ?..

Comment: if you ask google "how to convert string to datetime in python" it'll give you a bunch of answers

Comment: Yuup !! Worked Thanks !